# Maven commands not working

Tags: maven

For some reason

```
mvc -version
```

is not working on my mac. Therefore I just decided to install it:

```
brew install maven
```

It worked and

```
mvc -version
```

is still not working. I get the following output:

```
-bash: mvc: command not found
```

I am trying to use JHiptster to create an app and the only thing not working is the:

```
mvc
```

commands.

Comment: try mvn instead of mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the command you are using is wrong...

try mvn instead of mvc